# How to correctly pass email and name to created customers in Stripe?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments

My current code is:
server (Node js)

```
app.post("/create-payment-intent", async (req, res) => {
    const { email, name } = req.body;
    const customer = await stripe.customers.create({ email, name });
    const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
      customer: customer.id,
      setup_future_usage: "off_session",
      amount: 2499,
      currency: "usd",
      automatic_payment_methods: { enabled: true }
    });
    res.send({ clientSecret: paymentIntent.client_secret });
});
```

client

```
<body>
    
        <form id="payment-form">
        <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter email address" required/>
        <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Full Name" required/>
        <div id="payment-element"></div>
        <button class="str" id="submit">
            <div class="spinner hidden" id="spinner"></div>
            <span id="button-text">Submit</span>
        </button>
        <div id="payment-message" class="hidden"></div>
    </form>

<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', async () => {
    const {publicKey, endPoint} = await fetch('/config').then((r) => r.json())
    const stripe = Stripe(publicKey)
    const endpoint = (endPoint)

    const email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    const name = document.getElementById('name').value;

    const response = await fetch("/create-payment-intent", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({email, name})
    })
    const { clientSecret } = await response.json();

    const appearance = { theme: 'flat' };
    const elements = stripe.elements({ clientSecret, appearance });
    const paymentElement = elements.create('payment')
    paymentElement.mount('#payment-element')

    const form = document.getElementById("payment-form")
    form.addEventListener('submit', async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setLoading(true);

        const {error} = await stripe.confirmPayment({
            elements,
            confirmParams: {
                return_url: (endpoint)
            }
        })
        if(error) {
        const message = document.getElementById("payment-message")
        message.innerText = error.message;
        }

        setLoading(false);
    })
})
</script>
</body>
```

7.17.23 UPDATE:

Well, I finally did it BUT - it only works if email and name fields are already filled before DOM loads (like I enter my email and name, reload page and my data still filled). So I tried to move the email and name inside the submit but it didn't work. Question is the same - how to pass email and name to already created customer but as I may guess I need to pass it inside the submit event and it should update the customer (because when form is loaded it already passes data from these fields)?

Comment: in your `stripe.confirmPayment` function call you are missing a property in `confirmParams`.  next to `return_url ` you should also pass `client_secret`. You are already returning it from your server :)

Comment: Oh, I see @PCDSandwichMan already explained it perfectly.

Comment: @Y.Gherbi Thank you! I finally did it but there is another question so if you know the answer or direction would be awesome to hear it :)

Comment: I spotted the issue! You can take a look at my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you just have your stripe method order a bit mixed up is all. In most cases you can follow this order:

1. Create a customer
2. Create a payment for your customer
3. Confirm the payment that you just made for your customer

So you server code would look something like this:

```js
app.post("/create-payment-intent", async (req, res) => {
  const { email, name } = req.body;

  // Step 1) Create a customer
  const customer = await stripe.customers.create({
    email: email,
    name: name,
  });

  // Step 2) Create a payment for your customer
  const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
    customer: customer.id,
    setup_future_usage: "off_session",
    amount: 2499,
    currency: "usd",
    automatic_payment_methods: { enabled: true },
  });

  // Send the client_secret to the frontend so we can confirm the payment
  res.send({ clientSecret: paymentIntent.client_secret });
});
```

And your frontend code would look something like this:

```html
<form id="payment-form">
  ...
  <button class="str" id="submit">Submit</button>
  ...
</form>

<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', async () => {
      ...
      const form = document.getElementById("payment-form")
      form.addEventListener('submit', async (e) => {
          e.preventDefault();

          const email = document.getElementById("email").value;
          const name = document.getElementById("name").value;

          const response = await fetch("/create-payment-intent", {
              method: "POST",
              headers: {
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
              },
              body: JSON.stringify({ email: email, name: name })
          })

          const { clientSecret } = await response.json()


          // Step 3) Confirm the payment that you just made for your customer
          const { error } = await stripe.confirmPayment({
              elements,
              confirmParams: {
                  client_secret: clientSecret, // <--- This is the client secret that you got from the server
                  return_url: (endpoint)
              }
          })

          if(error) {
              const message = document.getElementById("payment-message")
              message.innerText = error.message;
          }
      })
  })
</script>
```

Comment: I found this explanation really helpful, thank you! I did notice that the code example included some parts that were already functioning correctly, just with comments describing what it does. Is there a specific reason for this? As a reader, it seemed to take a little extra time to identify the necessary changes. Just curious to learn from your approach.

Comment: Yeah, you're probably right. I'm really not a teacher, just another dev trying to help someone.

Comment: Would be nice to have more people like that on this website, haha. I appreciate that! Maybe consider updating your answer?

I very much like your website!! Don't mind me "steeling" the background words thing you have implemented?

Comment: @PCDSandwichMan Thank you for your help! I updated my questions and maybe you know  how to achieve that goal. If not - anyway thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer to your question after update (7.17.23 UPDATE)

Based on your description and the code you've shared, it appears the `email` and `name` variables are being assigned at the time of the `DOMContentLoaded` event. This means that the input fields' values are fetched as soon as the document has been completely loaded, which explains why the fields need to be prefilled for the code to work.

Instead, you want to fetch the input field values at the time the form is submitted, i.e., inside the `submit` event handler.

Try moving these lines:

```js
const email = document.getElementById('email').value;
const name = document.getElementById('name').value;
```

inside the `submit` event handler, like so:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', async () => {
    const {publicKey, endPoint} = await fetch('/config').then((r) => r.json())
    const stripe = Stripe(publicKey)
    const endpoint = (endPoint)

    const form = document.getElementById("payment-form")
    form.addEventListener('submit', async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const email = document.getElementById('email').value;
        const name = document.getElementById('name').value;

        const response = await fetch("/create-payment-intent", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({email, name})
        })
        const { clientSecret } = await response.json();

        const appearance = { theme: 'flat' };
        const elements = stripe.elements({ clientSecret, appearance });
        const paymentElement = elements.create('payment')
        paymentElement.mount('#payment-element')

        setLoading(true);

        const {error} = await stripe.confirmPayment({
            elements,
            confirmParams: {
                return_url: (endpoint)
            }
        })
        if(error) {
            const message = document.getElementById("payment-message")
            message.innerText = error.message;
        }

        setLoading(false);
    })
})
```

This way, the `email` and `name` variables will be assigned the values from the input fields at the time the form is submitted. After that, a fetch request is made to the `/create-payment-intent` endpoint with the entered email and name. The response from this request is then used to create the payment element and confirm the payment.